# Matrix representation of a linear operator given an arbitrary basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Prove or give a counterexample.
>
> Let $L:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be a linear operator. For each basis $\alpha$ of $\Bbb R^3$ there always exists a basis $\beta$ of $\Bbb R^3$ such that the matrix $L_\alpha^\beta$ is given by
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Let's analyse it a bit. We see that all elements of the $\alpha$ basis of $\Bbb R^3$ are going to be mapped to themselves except for $v_3$, which is mapped to zero (i.e. $v_3 \in \ker(L)$).

Let's work with the standard basis $\alpha=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

We of course have that $L(1,0,0)=(1,0,0), L(0,1,0)=(0,1,0)$ and $L(0,0,1)=(0,0,0)$. If we write these vectors as a linear combination of $\beta=\alpha$ we clearly get the stated matrix.

Let's work with another basis; $\alpha=\{(2,0,0),(0,5,0),(0,0,6)\}$.

We get $L(2,0,0)=(2,0,0), L(0,5,0)=(0,5,0)$ and $L(0,0,6)=(0,0,0)$. The linear combinations yield information on what $\beta$ equals to

$$\begin{aligned}(2,0,0)&= 1(2,0,0)+0(0,5,0)+0(a,b,c)\\(0,5,0)&=0(2,0,0)+1(0,5,0)+0(a,b,c)\\(0,0,0)&=0(2,0,0)+0(0,5,0)+0(a,b,c)\end{aligned}$$

So we indeed get the stated matrix if $\beta = \{(2,0,0), (0,5,0), (a,b,c)\}$, where $(a,b,c) \notin \operatorname{span}((2,0,0), (0,5,0))$.

So I'd say the statement is true. We pick $\alpha = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, and there's always going to exist $\beta = \{v_1, v_2, c\}$ where $c \notin \operatorname{span}(v_1, v_2)$.

However, the above does not look like a proof to me. Is what I have done OK? If not, what am I missing?

**EDIT**

OK The statement is false. User1551 and TheSilverDoe proposed two counterexamples

$1)$ Take the zero map (i.e. $\ker(L)=\Bbb R^3$)

In this case the matrix representation of the linear map is of course

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Which does not match the provided matrix.

$2)$ Take the identity map (i.e. $\ker(L)=\{0\}$)

In this case the matrix representation of the linear map (wrt the standard basis) is of course

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Which does not match the provided matrix.

Comment: If $\mathrm{Ker}(L)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, how can you find the vector $v_3$ that must satisfy $L(v_3)=0$ ?

Comment: Hi again! :) If $\mathrm{Ker}(L)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace \Rightarrow v_3=0$, where $v_3 \in \Re^3$. But I do not get where you're driving me.

Comment: The arrow $\text{“}\mapsto\text{''}$ distinguishes the function $x\mapsto x^2 y^3$ from the function $y\mapsto x^2 y^3,$ and the simpler arrow $\text{“}\to\text{''}$ is used in things like $f:A\to B.$ I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: $L_\alpha^\beta$ is in the given form if and only if $L$ has rank $2$. Therefore the answer is negative. $L=0$ gives a trivial counterexample.

Comment: @JD_PM If you can find two basis such that the matrix of $L$ has the given form, then the third vector of your basis must satisfy $L(v_3)=0$. It also has to be non-zero, because it belongs to a basis... Do you think that it is possible if $\mathrm{Ker}(L) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ ?

Comment: I see you both have different counterexamples in mind: user1551 suggests the zero map (i.e. $Ker(L) = \Re^3$) and TheSilverDoe a map with $\mathrm{Ker}(L) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ (i.e. an injective map). I am trying to work them out now.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Mmm but I do not see where's my mistake above. $(a,b,c)$ is always multiplied by zero so the only restriction is that it must be linearly independent to the other two elements of $\beta$ (i.e. $(a,b,c) \notin \operatorname{span}(v_1, v_2))$. Answering your question: it is not possible. However, how did you construct your counterexample?

Comment: After some thoughts I think I got your point. Could you please have a look at my edit? Is that what you meant? Thanks.

Comment: In addition to the counterexamples already provided (the zero map and the identity map), it's not even true for an arbitrary rank 2 operator. The given matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ is diagonal, so if $L$ is not diagonalizable, there is no basis with respect to which it has that matrix. Moreover, the eigenvalues of a diagonal matrix are the diagonal elements, namely $1$ (with multiplicity $2$), and $0$ (with multiplicity $1$). So, unless $L$ has exactly these eigenvalues, there is no basis for which its matrix has the given form.

Comment: Don't use `\Re`, it's confusing and it denotes the real part of a complex number. Use `\Bbb R` instead.

Comment: @Invisible I have to confess I do it because I always forget the standard LaTeX command haha.

Comment: @JD_PM In your edit, you seem to say that the matrix representing an injective map in any bases is the identity. This is not true ! This is true iff the map *is* the identity, i.e. the map $L(x)=x$. For other injective map, the matrix is not the identity ; but the point is that it cannot have a column of zeros.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I agree it was misleading. I've just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

$L_\alpha^\beta=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$ iff $L$ has rank $2$. Hence every $L$ whose rank $\ne2$ serves as a counterexample.

Let $E$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Since every nonsingular matrix can be viewed as a basis transition matrix,
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{rank}(L)=2
&\Leftrightarrow \operatorname{rank}(L_E^E)=2\\
&\Leftrightarrow L_E^E=U\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)V
\ \text{ for some nonsingular $U$ and $V$}\\
&\Leftrightarrow L_E^E=I_\beta^E\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)I_E^\alpha
\quad (U=I_\beta^E,\ V=I_E^\alpha)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)=I_E^\beta L_E^E I_\alpha^E=L_\alpha^\beta.
\end{aligned}
Alternatively, suppose $L_\alpha^\beta=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$. Let $\alpha=\{u,v,w\}$ and $\beta=\{x,y,z\}$. Then $L(u)=x,\,L(v)=y$ and $L(w)=0$. Hence $L(\mathbb R^3)=\operatorname{span}\{x,y\}$ and $\operatorname{rank}(L)=2$.

Conversely, suppose $\operatorname{rank}(L)=2$. Then $\dim L(\mathbb R^3)=2$ and $\dim\ker(L)=1$. Pick a basis $\{x,y\}$ of $L(\mathbb R^3)$ and pick a nonzero vector $w\in\ker(L)$. Since $x$ and $y$ are two linearly independent images of $L$, we have $x=L(u)$ and $y=L(v)$ for some linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$. Hence $\alpha=\{u,v,w\}$ is linearly independent and it is a basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Now complete $\{x,y\}$ to a basis $\beta=\{x,y,z\}$ of $\mathbb R^3$. Then $L_\alpha^\beta=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0)$.